# Trying to parse data from MongoDB to JSON using Pymongo, and then return a list in the DOM

Tags: python, json, flask, pymongo, bson

I'm a total newbie to Python and Flask. This is essentially a database of students. Each document contains a `first_name`, `last_name`, `student_id` and `major`. I want the list to display when `/view-students` is visited. The code:

```
@app.route("/view-students")
def view_students():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = mongo.db.students
    for student in students.find():
        student = dumps(student)
        print(student)
    return render_template('view-students.html', student=student)
```

This gets returned as a string, or from what googling seems to show, BSON:

```
{"last_name": "Down", "student_id": "u6003698", "first_name": "Alec", "_id": {"$oid": "5ae0f4ca78ba1481a6284e83"}, "major": "German Literature"}
{"last_name": "Doe", "student_id": "u0000000", "first_name": "John", "_id": {"$oid": "5ae0f4f178ba1481a6284e84"}, "major": "Electrical Engineering"}
```

On the client side, I basically want to do something like this:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Student ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Major</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for student in students %}
      <tr>
        {{students.first_name}}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I've tried using jsonify, json dumps, json-utils, and all just seem to either give me a string or tell me that it can't be serialized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a variable inside a template, it should not be jsonized or dumped. Also, you are passing `student` variable (defined inside for loop) but using `students` in the template. And looping but not accessing the right variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a list as argument, no need to dump the content:

```
@app.route("/view-students")
def view_students():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = list(mongo.db.students.find())
    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)
```

And iterate on the template using `student` and not `students` (note the **s**):

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Student ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Major</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for student in students %}
      <tr>
        {{student.first_name}}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: This did it. The big thing I was getting wrong was attaching the `.find()` to the wrong place. Thank you!